# Best way to add comments in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, erb, block-comments

How do we add comments in erb files, if we do not want them to be generated into the html content?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Use the `<%# %>` sequence, e.g.

```
<%# This is a great comment! %>
```

Comment: I used to use this format until I noticed it just raised an error on someones computer in my team (we were both using linux, but different distros), regardless I avoid it since..

Comment: It's one of only a few supported ERB tags. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html If it didn't work on their PC, they either had a typo, or they weren't using real ERB. However, I've run into issues with code like this <% for foo in bar # loop over bar %>..  This was OK in the ERB that shipped with 1.8.6, but when I switched to 1.8.7, it caused lots of problems.

Comment: i.e. there can't be any space between `<%` and `#`

Comment: How can i get textmate to generate these style of comments with apple-/

Comment: @Mike Ctrl+Shift+Period (i.e. Ctrl+GreaterThan) 4 times quickly should do it.

Comment: This occasionally fails in some rubys... I find you need to put the closing "%>" tag on a newline... which feels a bit kludgy, but means you don't suddenly find half your template disappears on production, even though it works find on development :P

Comment: @TarynEast: be sure there aren't any characters between `<%` and `#`

Comment: I have some problem commenting this  <li><%= link_to "News", news_path %></li>  ... since I have "%>" already in the erb. How should I comment "<li><%= link_to "News", news_path %></li> "??

Comment: By the way, for those using sublimetext2 .. check out https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB

Comment: I was using this but found it doesn't work if I want to comment out a section of existing code that already contains a closing tag %> (because the comment ends at the first closing tag). So now I'm using the <% if false %> <%end%> suggestion by user user3212755. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 53):

For Record

```
<%# This is a great comment! %>

<%#= This is a great comment! %>
```

Comment: The `<%=` -> `<%#=` example is useful. It doesn't require a special case and [isn't documented](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). It works and is the easiest, though! (Beats having to guess whether there was an `=` when uncommenting it.)

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @TravisR: The first one is just a comment, the second is also just a comment but probably arises when you're trying to disable a `<%= ... %>` by turning it into a comment.

Comment: Here's more info on [What is the difference difference between '<%#' and '<%#=' in ERB comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538995/what-is-the-difference-difference-between-and-in-erb-comments?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 35):

For block comments:

```
<% if false %>
    code to be commented out...
<% end %>
```

Comment: For blocks you can just add line breaks inside the `<%# %>` tag.

Comment: Would probably still give errors for broken code in the comment

Answer (score 7):

I have a Windows setup, and this <%-# %> sequence is the only one that works for me:

Example:

```
<%-# This is a sample comment! %>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my text editor, i run `command + /` (sublime-text shortcut). It will be like this.

```
<%
=begin%>
    Here is the comment 
<%
=end%>
```

It doesn't look simply, but it works.

Comment: This works as hoped in .ERB files where one wants to comment out multiple statements all at once. An explanation of what is actually happening would be a good addition to the answer.

Comment: what is `command` in this context?

Answer (score 3):

Since .erb is "embedded ruby" by definition, you can embed any ruby code between: `<%=`  and the other: `%>`, typically all written in one line. In addition, ruby one-line comments start always with `#`, so the `<%=# Comment %>` style matches perfectly with both pure-ruby and erb styles for one-line comments.

Comment: This does not work 
`<html>
  <body>
  <form method="POST" action="www.some-url.com">
    <input id="data" name="data" value="<%=# "String" %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>` throws an error

Comment: @Epigene Likely cause of the error is the inner quotes.  Not sure why you'd want to do this, but to get rid of the error, try:
`value="<%=# 'String' %>"`

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't work in the Controllers files, I had to put it between slashes

/ comment here.... /

Answer (score 0):

In Embedded Ruby (ERB), which is commonly used in Ruby on Rails applications, you can add comments using the `<%# ... %>`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to StackOverflow! The answer you provided is good by itself, but is just a duplicate of the [already accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774858/455269). In these cases, just upvote the accepted answer instead of posting a duplicate.