# SyntaxError in Campaign_groups#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, show, erb

I have looked at this a lot and just cannot find the syntax error, I keep getting:

```
compile error
/home/durrantm/code/it_trunk/webapp/app/views/campaign_groups/_cgs_overview.html.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected kELSE, expecting ')'
;  else ; @output_buffer.concat "\n  ...
       ^
/home/durrantm/code/it_trunk/webapp/app/views/campaign_groups/_cgs_overview.html.erb:40: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'
;  end ; @output_buffer.concat "\n\n"
      ^
/home/durrantm/code/it_trunk/webapp/app/views/campaign_groups/_cgs_overview.html.erb:43: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
/home/durrantm/code/it_trunk/webapp/app/views/campaign_groups/_cgs_overview.html.erb:45: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting ')'
```

The entire code for the page (_cgs_overview.html.erb) is:

```
<% if @campaign_group.campaigns.count > 0 %>
    <%=# render :partial => 'show_offer_images' %>
    <div class="overview">

      <table class="show_activity show_overview">
        <tr>
          <th>Unique Shoppers</th>
          <td id="overview-shoppers" class="clearable">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Issuances</th>
          <td id="overview-issuances" class="clearable">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Redemptions</th>
          <td title="Redemption rate does not include informational campaigns" id="overview-redemptions" class="clearable">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Total Cost</th>
          <td id="overview-cost" class="clearable">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Products</th>
          <td id="overview-products" class="clearable">-</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div style="width:300px; padding-bottom: 10px">
      <%=# link_to("<<", campaign_group_path(params[:id], :offer_images_offset_for_pagination => @previous_images_to_paginate )) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%=# link_to(">>", campaign_group_path(params[:id], :offer_images_offset_for_pagination => @next_images_to_paginate )) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <%=# link_to(">ajax>", :remote => true, :action => 'show_offer_images', :campaign_group_id => params[:id], :offer_images_offset_for_pagination => @next_images_to_paginate ) %>
    </div>

<% else %>
    <p style="font-size:120%;font-style:italic;margin:140px 0 160px;">
      There are no campaigns in this group.
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: break it down in halves, localize it, like git bisect does

Comment: first thing you should do is to remove all those commented lines like `<%=# render :partial => .... %>` and try again

Comment: Thanks guys I have tried the above before posting.  Still stuck.  This one is really weird which is why I am posting it

Comment: i removed the middle html table and replaced it wit ';table' but no luck

Answer (score 1):

If you let `erb` show you the ruby code, via the `-x` switch, you will see

```
... _erbout.concat((# render :partial ...)); _erbout.concat "\n"
```

Note how the `#` hash comments the whole rest of the line out. This line and three others like it are the cause for "`expecting ')'`".

Searching for *erb comment* points to [Best way to add comments in erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774841/best-way-to-add-comments-in-erb) where we learn that you should replace `<%=# ... %>` with `<%#= ... %>`