# Why is everything in my database (create and update times, topic_id, post_id) displaying in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, erb

I'm new to programming and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 6 weeks. I've added commenting functionality to my app, and while comments are being displayed properly, so is everything else in the (sqlite3) database associated with the comment - created_at, updated_at, comment_id, post_id. 
The partial that displays comments has the following code:

```
<%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>
  <p><%= @comments.each do |comment| %></p>
  <small>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </small>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm only trying to display the comment body, but I'm displaying everything.

Here is the create method from the comments controller:

```
def create  
   @post =  Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = current_user.comments.build(params_comment)
   @comment.post = @post
   authorize @comment

   if @comment.save
     flash[:notice] = "Comment was created"
     redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
   else 
     flash[:error] = "Comment failed to save"
     redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
   end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure why everyting is displaying if I'm only calling .body on comment. I've researched this problem but haven't found anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix :-

```
<%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>
  <!-- Here I removed `=` from `<%` %> -->
  <p><% @comments.each do |comment| %></p> 
  <small>
  <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </small>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

`#each` returns the collection when the block is finished with full iteration. Now, you used `<%= ..%>`, which then printing the return value of `#each`. But if `<%..%>`, it wouldn't print although the `@comments.each` still returning the `@comments` collection.

Comment: [`erb` commenting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774841/best-way-to-add-comments-in-erb) is not working. Anybody, if know how to do, please edit my answer.