# Rails, leaving comments in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

I dont know why i cant leave comments , they show up on my website, p.s,  I dont really know anything about code, just following a template for fun

I currently dont have a website or email to link to, so i tried to leave a comment to block examples so they dont show up on my page, but they do

```
<ul>
       <li class="category">Social</li>

      #<li><a href="https://website.com">WebsiteName</a></li>

      #<li><a href="mailto:name@name.com">MyEmail</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try:
<!-- <li><a href="https://website.com">WebsiteName</a></li>-->

Comment: Thanks everyone the <!-- -->  works

Comment: You forgot to upvote my comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

If it is plain html, the way to comment a line is:

```
<!-- li><a href="https://website.com">WebsiteName</a></li -->
```

See [The Importance of Correct HTML Commenting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/The_Importance_of_Correct_HTML_Commenting) for more details.

If it is ruby code in the view, the way to comment a line is:

```
<%# This is a great comment! %>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774858/429758 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Comment block like this:

```
<!--
<ul>
       <li class="category">Social</li>

      <li><a href="https://website.com">WebsiteName</a></li>

      <li><a href="mailto:name@name.com">MyEmail</a></li>
</ul>
-->
```